# Facebook Messenger alternative for Windows 10

Tags: windows, facebook

I'm looking for a substitution for **Facebook Messenger**. I've used FBM for years but suddenly (after an automatic Win update) it stopped taking keyboard input. I'm using the latest Win10 version.

I'm not rushing into finding a fix without doing a lot of Google research on this problem. I've tried at least 6 different suggestions during my search, but none has worked. Many posts point to the keyboard autocorrect function. Shutting this off has no effect in my version of Win10. I see that this problem dates back to Win7 but has never been fixed by Facebook.

As I cannot find a fix I am looking for an *alternative messenger app*. Does an app exist that will allow me to change to something that does not require my contacts to change anything on their end?

Comment: Try Telegram it has desktop version

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you are looking for an alternate FBM client or if you're entirely open to other networks.

Comment: Daniel, I'm looking for a substitute for FBM that will not impact my Messenger contacts. Otherwise, I don't want to have to contact each of my contacts and tell them I've changed. Is there such a thing as importing my FBM contacts into say Telegraph? Possibly I misunderstand how these texting apps work. Is it as simple as installing another texting app and re-intering the old FBM contacts manually?